# Ruby on Rails: assets search with fallback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, themes, asset-pipeline

I have a site that need theming support. Theme is combination of assets and views.

Views search pathes are easily handled with before filter adding views search path: `prepend_view_path Rails.root.join('views', theme.name).to_s`

But what about assets? I can't find any way to add directory there on per request basis.
How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know how to prepend some dirs for assests, but I can propose some workarounds for assets changing problem.
You can set particular assets at each of your themed views manually (If you are already switching views, so they just can contain all needed content to be rendered correctly). Or define some helper method that will return paths to assets according to chosen theme, and then provide all asset calls through this helper (or maybe helpers)

Comment: I thought about helper method that will load resources based on view path, but first I want to ensure there's no standard method like with views.